# Parse Facebook User logged in, perform segue

Tags: ios, xcode, facebook, swift, parse-platform

I am trying to skip over my login view once a user is logged in. How can I check to see if a user is logged in through Facebook while the app is starting?

I currently have the following code in a **LoginViewController**:

```
override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    var loggedIn = PFFacebookUtils.session().isOpen;

    if (loggedIn) {
        performSegueWithIdentifier("skipLogin", sender: self)
    }

}
```

[image]

This does not move to my next view even after the user has clicked the "Log in with Facebook" button.

I get the following error:

> Warning: Attempt to persent <_Project.HomeViewController: 0x7fa331d3af00> on
>   <_Project.LoginViewController: 0x7fa331f08950> whose view is not in the window hierarchy!

Comment: I have changed the sender to `self`, but the view does not perform the segue.

Comment: Does `loggedIn` equals to `true`? Did you check that the segue in the interface designer is indeed named `loggedIn`?

Comment: Yes, I just checked. `loggedIn` is true. And yes, the segue identifier was `loggedIn`. I have renamed it to `skipLogin` so there isn't confusion.

Comment: OK, your warning wasn't present in the initial version of your question. Try to put your code in `viewDidLoad` instead of `viewWillAppear`.

Comment: I tried this, no results. I added a pic of my storyboard as well.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/71295/discussion-between-atwalsh04-and-romain).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As discussed in chat, you have basically two options here:

- Let the user "see" the animation from the login view controller to the second one. In that case you should do the push in `viewDidAppear` instead of `viewWillAppear` (where the view is not fully prepared, as the runtime warning clearly states).
- If you prefer showing the final view controller immediately, without any animation, then it's better to put that logic inside your app delegate, and choose which initial view controller should be loaded from here. In that case, you're not actually performing any segue, you're just assigning one or another view controller to the main window (or your navigation controller).

Parse has the "AnyWall" sample app that implements the second logic. See here for more details: https://parse.com/tutorials/anywall#2-user-management. In particular, the chapter 2.4 is of special interest, as it explains how you can keep a user logged-in.

Simply put, here's how they did it (I've adapted their Objective-C code to Swift):

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
    ...
    navigationController = UINavigationController()
    ...
    // If we have a cached user, we'll get it back here
    if PFFacebookUtils.session().isOpen {
        // A user was cached, so skip straight to the main view
        presentWallViewController(animated: false)
    } else {
        // No cached user, go to the welcome screen and 
        // have them log in or create an account.
        presentLoginViewController(animated: true)
    }   
   ...
    window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds)
    window.rootViewController = navigationController
    window.makeKeyAndVisible()

    return true
}
```

In each of the two methods `present...ViewController`, they use the following skeleton:

```
func presentxxxViewController(#animated: Bool) {
    NSLog("Presenting xxx view controller")
    // Go to the welcome screen and have them log in or create an account.
    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil) // Here you need to replace "Main" by the name of your storyboard as defined in interface designer
    let viewController = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("xxx") as xxxViewController // Same here, replace "xxx" by the exact name of the view controller as defined in interface designer
    //viewController.delegate = self
    navigationController?.setViewControllers([viewController], animated: animated)
}
```

The `navigationController` and `window` vars should be defined like this in `AppDelegate`:

```
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {
    var window: UIWindow?
    var navigationController: UINavigationController?
    ...
}
```

If your app also uses a navigation controller as its root view controller, you can probably use the same code.

Comment: I'm having trouble getting a couple things to work in Swift. Would you be able to show me how the "skeleton" should look in Swift?

Comment: Awesome, thanks. However I have run into another issue. [Here](https://gist.github.com/adamtwalsh/94299a86aacc6fc169da) is what I'm using. Lines 19-20 & 28-29 give errors. I can't figure it out. I have made sure the view controllers have the correct storyboard id's.

Comment: You can safely remove lines 19 & 28 for now. They are directly linked to the AnyWall parse example. As for lines 20 & 29, how did you set up your storyboard? Do you have a navigation controller as the main view controller? In the AnyWall example, they create a navigation controller by code and attach it to the main window. I've updated my answer to explain it.

Comment: Just saw your storyboard screenshot... If you use AnyWall's method, you can safely remove the navigation controller that you have created in your storyboard, as you will now be creating it by code (see my answer: it corresponds to the following lines: `self.navigationController = UINavigationController()` and `self.window.rootViewController = self.navigationController`). In the end, in your storyboard, you would just have two independent view controllers: one for login and one for your main view once the user is logged in.